# HtmlAgilityPack search website for string of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, loops, html-agility-pack

I am writing a small program that searches different websites for certain words. If the specific word is not or no longer available I want to have an error message.

I want to keep the code relatively compact and therefore use arrays for the URLs and the words.

Unfortunately it seems that you can only search single strings:

```cs
string checkWord = doc[0].DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(., 'Word1')]]").InnerText;

// (= no error)
```

But I want to have the whole command in a loop and use an array of all words instead of 'Word1', so that every website is automatically searched for the respective word:
Unfortunately it seems that you can only search single strings:

```cs
string checkWord = doc[i].DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(., 
        word[i])]]").InnerText;

// (= error)
```

Does anyone know how I can enter a variable (array) in the string instead of a specific text?

I hope I was able to explain my problem in an understandable way and there is someone who can help me :)

Ps. the whole script would be something like:

```cs
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

string[] words = new string[] {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
HtmlDocument[] doc = new HtmlDocument[] {web.Load("www.url1.com"), web.Load("www.url2.com"), web.Load("www.url3.com"),};


for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
{
    try()
    {
        string checkWord = doc[i].DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(., 
        words[i])]]").InnerText;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} is not avaiable", i);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you provide a text file with the urls and the words, the script can then check these pages and return those that contain any of the words you provided.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! How can I read text files? Sry im pretty new to c#.

Comment: you can use `System.IO.File`

Comment: BTW, there's no point to use HAP for finding words on a web page. You could just load the page with C# and check if it contains any of the words. That would be a lot faster in terms of performance. HAP is used to find words in specific locations, hence it supports xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to just use `SelectNodes("//text()")` to grab all the text nodes and then a LINQ statement back in C# land to do the contains.

For example, this code will return all the words that exist on the loaded page:

```
string[] words = new string[] { "jesse", "jessehouwing", "word3" };
var web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument[] doc = new HtmlDocument[] { web.Load("https://jessehouwing.net") };


for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
{
    var check = doc[i].DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")
        .SelectMany(node => words.Where(word => node.InnerText.Contains(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
        .Distinct();
}
```

Results:

[image: Showing the 2 matching words on the loaded page.]

Comment: Can be simplified with the following to reduce the need for filtering null values. `doc[i].DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()").SelectMany(node => words.Where(word => node.InnerText.Contains(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))).Distinct();`

Comment: PS: Do keep in mind that the HTML Agility pack loads the exact contents returned by the webserver without executing any Javascript. It your target websites load their content dynamically in the browser the HTML Agility pack won't do what you expect. In that case you need to use a headless browser to load the page and render its contents. For example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PuppeteerSharp/